# Warn my employer

Tags: resignation, software-development, canada

I'm actually kind of new in my company (been here for 4 months now) and my boss has been really kind to me in the way of giving me responsabilities and thrusting my judgement.

I'm a programmer analyst but at this job my title is software developer. I'm pretty sure we should be at least too programmer for the whole factory because there's a lot of project and even more major projects.

Right now I'm starting a major project to connect and add traceability to most of the production plant. It's been something that was asked a lot and they are really behind in their schedule for that.

I wasn't looking for a new job, but I just had an opportunity and it's going really well.
There's only one interview left to know if they are going to take me, but everyone at the new opportunity said that it's pretty clear that I'll be a part of the team.

I know usually when there's nothing signed and official you shouldn't even mentionned to your boss that there's maybe an opportunity elsewhere.

The thing right now is that there's really but a few people on the market, so my current job will have a really hard time to hire someone soon. They have major projects and I really think that when I leave (if I have the job) that the whole company will be behind their schedule a lot in means of their project.

### The question

My boss has been really kind to me and I'd hate to see all this project go down because I'm leaving. I really thought there should be more than one programmer/software dev in this factory. I thought I could say that I'm not looking for another job, but a one in a lifetime opportunity came to me. That way they could start looking for someone else right now and I could bring up just before saying that there's a new opportunity that we should be at least two doing this job?

My feeling after writting all of this is that I shouldn't mention it to my boss.
Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My boss has been really kind to me and I'd hate to see all this project go down because I'm leaving. I really thought there should be more than one programmer/software dev in this factory. I thought I could say that I'm not looking for another job, but a one in a lifetime opportunity came to me. That way they could start looking for someone else right now and I could bring up just before saying that there's a new opportunity that we should be at least two doing this job?

Ultimately it's not *your* responsibility that your employer took the risk inherent in only having one person with a given skillset, this is business - people leave all the time, or fall ill, or get hit by a rogue ice-cream truck.

Heck it's not even necessarily that they made the *wrong* decision either - the extra cost/hassle associated with replacing that one person when they leave isn't pleasant certainly, but the flip side is that to avoid it they would essentially have to *double* their cost (by employing two) all the time.

It's great that you've had a good relationship with your boss - and I'm sure you'll do your best to repay that during your notice period by giving them the best handover you can, but you absolutely **must** put yourself first and that means:

> I know usually when there's nothing signed and official you shouldn't even mentioned to your boss that there's maybe an opportunity elsewhere.

still applies here, if your sure you'll take this new opportunity if it comes to fruition then keep it on the down low until it's all signed and sealed.

Comment: You got me with the rogue ice-cream truck. Thanks for the advice, I think putting myself before is something I need to work on. Thanks for giving me your POV it helped!

Answer (score 3):

First, don't tell your boss until after you have an offer letter in hand.  The offer might not come through for any of a variety of reasons, or the offer might not be as good as you're expecting.  Perhaps they really lowball you on the salary, for example.  Once you *do* have the offer letter in hand, and have decided to make the switch, *then* it is time to let your boss know - and, if you wish to be kind, try to give them a pretty hefty notice period.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks for confirming that. The hefty notice period is actually a great idea, thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 1):

> My boss has been really kind to me and I'd hate to see all this project go down because I'm leaving. I really thought there should be more than one programmer/software dev in this factory. I thought I could say that I'm not looking for another job, but a one in a lifetime opportunity came to me. That way they could start looking for someone else right now and I could bring up just before saying that there's a new opportunity that we should be at least two doing this job?

Unfortunately this is a tactic used on millennials by corporations. They know many people from this generation seek a rewarding, promising career where they're the main ingredient that's keeping it all together. You fell for it and for good reasons: you wanted it and you said so yourself that you found a job where you're the most important piece.

Truth is the boss is going to make you feel bad for leaving. He's going to say he's going to miss you and maybe he will. But truth is what he's trying to do is buy some time so he can find your replacement and once he does, you can expect to be forced to quit and get put into a position of emergency where you're forced to find a job that you might not like.

With that said, if you found a job switch to it. Give your proper notice (2 weeks in USA normally but outside of USA you might have different notice and if you're a contractor that needs to give some different notice), then work your 2 weeks ignoring the potential guilt trip that they might try to make you feel. Then go enjoy your new job. By the second or third job change, most people will not be asking these questions because ultimately, you live your life and your job provides you that lifestyle. If you feel, for whatever reason to change jobs, then it is best to go with that feeling instead of staying somewhere just because someone likes you. They'd have no problem throwing you out should they need to.

Comment: Thanks for saying that, I would have not seen it this way! I didn't think it would be a tactic widely used. I'm pretty sure like the way you said that they would kick me out in a blink if they had to. I'll give a proper notice (btw in Canada it's 2 weeks too) and try to not feel too much guilt. Thanks again!

Comment: While I agree with the answer provided by @Dan, it's also important to point out, your boss could legitimately provide a counter offer to have you continue to (permanently) work there. Only you can determine if you can trust such an offer from your boss.  Historically, counter offers, normally involve a catch.  Once you have indicated you are thinking of leaving a company, that company would be crazy, to not consider potentially finding a replacement for you. There is a reason people indicate the best way to get a raise, is with a job offer, because typically jobs are bound to become stagnant.

Comment: @Donald It's kind of a risk-vs-reward type thing. My recommendation is if you want higher pay, first ask your current employer for one. Tell them why, show your reasons and just see what they say. If they give you a generic reason or if you don't feel happy about the answer, then go find a new job. If somehow they're able to magically pay your desired salary, I would take that with a grain of salt. How can you trust someone who weeks ago told you no, then suddenly with you leaving, they can come up with the dough? That means they always could but didn't want to.